# Is there a way to search for an object in a list by a parameter in python?

Tags: python, list, object

I have a function in my program that updates an object stored in a list, and another function that finds the position of objects in that list. All objects have an "id" parameter, and I was wondering if there is a way to search for an object in that list solely by using the "id" parameter

This is the `find_position()` function:

```
def find_position(self, object):
        for i in range(len(self._objectsList)):
            if self._objectsList[i] == object:
                return i
        return -1
```

Comment: You should have a go at changing your code so that it will find an object by id. I see no attempt here.

Comment: `next((obj for obj in objects if obj.id == id_to_look_for), None)` or `next(filter(lambda obj: obj.id == id_to_look_for, objects), None)`?

Comment: If you overwrite `__hash__(self)` you can use `index(obj)`.

Comment: @Detlef no, `index` doesn't use `__hash__`. It uses equality (and maybe identity as an optimization)

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can access the id attribute via object.id:

```
def find_position_by_id(self, id):
        for el in self._objectsList:
            if el.id == id:
                return self._objectsList.index(el)
        return -1
```

You could also think of using a dict inside your main object so store the other objects. The keys of the dict could be the id's of the other objects.

Answer (score 0):

As you're after the index of the first object with `.id` equal to some value and appear to want to capture that in a function:

```
def find_position_by_id(objects, identifier):
    return next((i for i, obj in enumerate(objects) if obj.id == identifier), -1)
```

Explained in a few steps:

- `enumerate(objects)` returns an iterable that generates tuples of indices and values of `objects`, i.e. `(0, objects[0])`, `(1, objects[1])` etc.
- `i for i, obj in enumerate(objects)` is a generator that takes those indices and values one at a time and assigns them to `i` and `obj`, generating only the values of `i` as it goes.
- `i for i, obj in enumerate(objects) if obj.id == identifier` is that same generator, but it only generates the values of `i` paired with objects `obj` that have an `.id` that's equal to `identifier`
- Wrapping that in `next(<iterable>, -1)`, you get only the first value from that generator, or `-1` if there are no values in the generator.

So, `next((i for i, obj in enumerate(objects) if obj.id == identifier), -1)` gets you what you need and you can wrap that in a function, or a method like in your example code.

Put together with some example data:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Obj:
    id: int
    value: str


objects = [Obj(10, 'Alice'), Obj(20, 'Bob'), Obj(30, 'Charlie')]


def find_position_by_id(xs, identifier):
    return next((i for i, x in enumerate(xs) if x.id == identifier), -1)


print(find_position_by_id(objects, 20))
```

Result:

```
1
```